# Get the field table Father Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So, i make this atribbuition in model **comment.rb**

```
has_one :user
```

And my form is this

```
<% @post.comments.each  do |com| %>
    Comentário<br><%= com.comment %>    
<% end %>
```

My question is, how do I get the user when make the comment ?

---

I have a problem, i make this atribbuition i comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
```

and this in user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
```

but this dont works:

```
  <% post.comments.each do |comment|   %>
    <div id="comments" >
      <%= comment.user.email %>
           <%= comment.comment %>
    </div>
   <%end%>
```

appear the error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

please what is the problem, in the create of the comment i make the atribbuition so , look:

```
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment],:user_id => current_user.id)
```

how i solve this error, please

Comment: You mean get the current user ? are you using an authentification framework like `Devise` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add this code `<%= com.user.username %>` for example to display the user's username